# Shared memory in C - Sharing strings

Tags: c, string, memory, shared

Could anyone tell me another way to share strings in C between processes using shared memory? I've only achieved this shoddy way using fors. I want to use something like strcpy or similars. With int is very simple, but when pointers start playing becames so dificult form me. Here is the way I've achived in order to look for other ways:

```
int memid,*nptr,i;
char mezua[50];
struct shmid_ds buff;


if ((memid=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,sizeof(mezua),0600|IPC_CREAT))<0){
    perror("shmget error");
    exit(-1);
}
printf("%d\n",memid);

if((nptr=(char*)shmat(memid,0,0))==(char*)-1){
    perror("shmat error");
    exit(-1);
}

printf("Sartu nahi duzun mezua:\n");
__fpurge(stdin);
scanf("%s",mezua);


for(i=0;i<strlen(mezua);i++){
    *(nptr+i)=mezua[i];
}  
//**HERE WOULD GO THE OTHER WAY TO COPY STRINGS INTO SHARED MEMORY**


for(i=0;*(nptr+i)!='\0';i++)
    printf("%c",*(nptr+i)); 
//**HERE WOULD GO THE OTHER WAY TO READ STRINGS FROM SHARED MEMORY**


if(shmdt(nptr)<0){
    perror("shmdt error");
    exit(-1);
    }

    if(shmctl(memid,IPC_RMID,&buff)==-1){
        perror("shmctl error");
        exit(-1);
    }
```

**Thanks a lot!**

Have a nice code!!

Comment: `for(i=0;i<strlen(mezua);i++){` is wrong, it doesn't copy the final '\0'

Comment: What do you mean with "sharing strings"? Better elaborate.

Comment: Change `int *nptr` to `char *nptr`. `nptr` should be character pointer as per your logic.

Comment: This code works fine, it's tested. Excuse me, but you are not answering my question. I want another way to write and read from shared memory.

Comment: Maybe rohan is in the correct way. But then can I use strcpy?

Comment: To copy a string into an other yes you can use strcpy, it will include the ending '\0'. Just make sure you have enough space in the destination

Comment: You might like to read `man strcpy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to read [`man strcpy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html).

Make `nptr` a `char*` and do

```
strcpy(nptr, mezua); /* Copies from mezuato SHM. */

....

strcpy(mezua, nptr); /* Copies form SHM to mezua. */
```